# Image proportional resizing

Tags: html, css, image

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mySQ7/).

There is a standart trick with `display:block;` and `max-width:100%;` for responsive images:

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If I resize the **width** of the container, my image fits this width and also automatically resizes it's own height. This is very great image behavior! Also it doesn't use Javascript.

So, is it possible to do the same trick by resizing the **height** of the container? I want this image to fit containers height and also automatically resize it's own width proportionally. Of course, without any Javascript, just CSS or any experimental CSS3 features (I know how to do it with Javascript, really).

Comment: I looked into this recently and could not find anything that didn't require JS  :-( Would be an incredibly useful feature for responsive web pages though!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
max-height: 100%;
```

Also, try not to work with tables - they behave (more) unpredictably than other display types.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/txySR/) a most basic example.

**EDIT:** Couldn't find a way to do this without JS. I have put two methods for you in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/8Zgdd/) - both could be used easily (I've used jQuery, but you don't have to). If that doesn't suffice, than good luck.

Comment: Actually, I need this image to be aligned middle and centered. So, with display:table it doesn't work. With flexbox image even not resizing :) Arrrrr…